# What can be causing this simple focus listener to do not work?

Tags: javascript, events, xul

```
function appFocus() {
    write("FOCUSED"); // write on the screen
}
appWin.addEventListener("focus", appFocus, false);
// appWin is my window
```

- This same code works well with other windows
- other listeners works well with this window

so, why specifically the `focus` event does not work with just this window? Please, share your thoughts.

Comment: With another window (that works), event if I do `window.onfocus=null` before and after the listener, it continues to work..

Comment: You say 'window', so is the element represented by `appWin` able to get focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

I have a window with an "onload" that focus the browser within the window. By removing this onload I get the "onfocus" event to work.

Comment: and that leads to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763147/how-to-listen-to-focus-event-of-a-window-with-a-browser