# How to listen to focus event of a window with a browser?

Tags: javascript, xul

By running this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="640" height="480"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    onload="">

    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            function onfocus() {
                dump("FOCUSED!\n");
            }
            window.addEventListener("focus", onfocus, false);
        ]]>
    </script>

    <browser id="gmail" type="content" src="http://gmail.com/" flex="1" />
    <button label="click here to remove the focus from the browser"/>

</window>
```

..you can see that the `window`'s focus event will be thrown **only if** the focus is **not** on the `browser`. I added a button in the bottom, so you can remove the focus from the browser and see what I mean:

- If the `button` is focused and you minimize and restore the window, you'll see the focus event occur.
- If the `browser` is focused and you minimize and restore the window, the focus event will **not** occur.

I need this focus event to happen when the `browser` has the focus, any idea how to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the activate event instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Wonder if I should I post it to bugzilla.